# VS Code Snippet - Change position of linked tabstops

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-snippets

I am currently switching from IntelliJ to VS Code for a project and want to take some of my custom live templates with me.

VS Code supports "User Snippets", but I can't get them to work like they do in IntelliJ.

I want to achieve the following output:

```js
console.log('variableName', variableName);
```

Now the thing is, I want my cursor to start right after the `,`  so I get IntelliSense for auto completion of a defined variable. Then that variable name should be placed in the string.

I am right at the start and know that tabstops with the same ID get the same value:

```json
    "console.log variable": {
        "scope": "javascript,typescript",
        "prefix": "cl",
        "body": [
            "console.log('${1}', ${1});",
            "$0"
        ],
        "description": "console.log variable with name"
    }
```

The problem with this is though, that the first tabstop is the start of the snippet and since I am inside a string I don't get IntelliSense for the variable name.

Is there a way to reverse the tabstop order of linked tabstops or anything similar that helps with the problem at hand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"Print to console": {
  "prefix": "clog",
  "body": [
    "console.log('${1:variable}', ${1:variable});$0"
  ],
  "description": "Log output to console"
}
```

Works but you have to press `Ctrl+Space` to get completion items.

Comment: Oh wow, that was way easier than expected. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Does this add anything to simply disabling the setting: `Editor > Suggest: Snippets Prevent Quick Suggestions`?  With no change in the original snippet of the question.  And no need for `Ctrl+Space`.

Comment: @Mark A new setting for me. But does not change the suggestions in snippets, I still need to use `Ctrl+Space` when disabled

Comment: Not sure what you are doing.  See https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/148523#issuecomment-1114548313 .  The setting is an alternative to `Ctrl+Space`.  I don't need both.  And are you just getting the `abc` text version of variable suggestions?

Comment: There is also a "bug" in snippet completions when using quick suggestions.  Try removing the quotes around the other `$1` and you will see what I mean.

Comment: @Mark I don't mind if it is an `abc` suggestion or a parameter suggestion, the result is the same, using `'${2:$1}'` is not handled correct to my mind, it is treated the same as `'${1}'`, I'm using it for years and this works for me, `Ctrl+Space` beats typing the whole lot every time

Answer (score 0):

You can also do something like:

```
"System.println(${1/(.*)/\"$1: \"/} + $1);$0"
```

This will do both tabstops "in the open" and give a combined intelliSense and then add the quotes when you tab out. Tested on Monkey C

There might be a more elegant way to utilize the transform...

I'm shocked the snippet syntax don't have a way to indicate the primary tabstop of a linked group, something like `$!1`.

Also, `Ctrl + Space` is `CMD + i` on a Mac - took me a while to figure out...

Comment: Please vote on github bug.... [link](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/195339)